# easy installed cx_Oracle but still can't find module

Tags: python, macos, oracle, bash

On Mac OS X 10.8.5
Downloaded the client software, added it to my bash profile, now ran:

```
easy_install cx_Oracle
Searching for cx-Oracle
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cx_Oracle/
Reading http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net
Reading http://starship.python.net/crew/atuining
Best match: cx-Oracle 5.1.2
Downloading http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/cx-oracle/cx_Oracle-5.1.2.tar.gz?download
error: None
```

Then I went to test my  script which is:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pwd@mydatabase/orcl')
print con.version
con.close()
```

Ran it and got hit by

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sqlTest.py", line 1, in <module>
import cx_Oracle
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You must download and install Oracle instantclient libs (including -dev). Which is not as easy because on MAC OSX as they were segfaulting any app for several years. Functional MAC OSX drivers were released by Oracle about two months ago. Which version of InstantClient do you have? From where did you download it?

Comment: I downloaded the latest one from the Oracle site, didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Ok. I assume it was version 12.1 does sqlplus work for you? Can you execute it without SEGFAULTing?

Comment: Its version 11.2 (for Oracle) everything is 64 bit.